# Correctly unblocking LSMSGCV filtered email?

Tags: email, google-apps, spam, spam-prevention, email-spam

Part of our product involves sending users a weekly email with a status report about their account, and once in a while we get the following reply from their spam filtering service saying the following:

```
LSMSGCV: You just sent an email to foo@bar.com - please reply

Did you send an email to: foo@bar.com from: foo2@bar.com?

If yes, it got caught as unsolicited email by our spam blocker. You can release the mail from spam quarantine by simply replying to this message. At the same time the spam blocker will recognize you as a trusted sender (from this email address) and automatically add you to my Allow list for this and any future communication.

Many illegal spammers forge email addresses to try to get past spam blocking software.  These spammers send hundreds of millions of spam messages a day, clogging email servers and wasting people’s time.  We regret that these spammers have forced us to send this message to you.

Original From: foo2@bar.com

Original To: foo@bar.com

LSMSGCV For more information about our spam blocking software please visit www.lightspeedsystems.com
```

The problem is that our `from` email address is not a real inbox, it's actually a google group (set up through google apps) that we use to make sure everybody who needs to can receive the reply to this email and answer from their personal company accounts.

For `LSMSGCV`, does it matter if the "unblocking" reply comes NOT from the original `from` address? Would that successfully whitelist our `from` address or would that be insufficient?